# Adding data to SQL tables in C#

Tags: c#, sql, database

This may or may not be a noob question, so I'm sure it should be solved easily enough.

I'm trying to use a table in a .mdf database for a contacts list programme I'm writing. For the ID for each of the entries I put, I've got an Identity seed of 1000, with in increment of 1. This works fine when I input things directly into the table. The first entry is 1000, the second is 1001 and so on. I put some text boxes onto the form, and dragged each data source from the table onto their respective text box, so that new entries can be added from the form. The first two entries, which I added directly into the table, show up fine on the form, with their ID as I've previously stated. It's when I try to add a new entry using the form and the controls that I've created that problems arise.

When I add a new entry, the Contact ID for the new entry is set to -1, then -2 and so on. Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Relevant snips:

First entry is in there and works fine

[image]

New entry has an ID of -1 for some reason

[image]

Comment: How should we know?  You have not posted any relevant code.

Comment: I dont think that is what is being stored once you save.  Some of the Provider objects do that for new items.

Answer (score 1):

It is default value for IDENTITY fields.

As far as you cannot know which will be the value of an IDENTITY fields unless you insert the record, by default it show -1

The best way to avoid it, it now showing this field when you dateset is on INSERT mode.

In fact, if you try to set it value manually, you will get an error.

Comment: I was under the impression that if you set the Identity seed to 1000, and set the identity increment to 1 in the properties of the ID column, then the identity would always be whatever the previous identity was +1, starting with 1000. Is this not the case?

Comment: And after you insert the record it will be inserted as 1001, 1002, 1003,... But meanwhile, your form doesn't know its value.

Comment: I see. So during the input process, it won't show the ID, only afterwards? Is there a way for me to make it show the next ID during the input?

Comment: No, by default you can't know it. I usually set read-only textboxes of identity fields.

Answer (score 0):

Make ID field read-only or don't show it altogether. The INSERT sql for your form should not include identity, i.e.

```sql
Insert into contacts (name, company, telephone, mobile, email) 
Output INSERTED.*
Values (. . . .  .)
```

If you in c# do `command.ExecuteReader` using above sql, you will get back all values including `ID`